# About the PIL Error -- IOError: decoder zip not available

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am getting the:

```
IOError: decoder zip not available
```

when I try to draw an image and save to a jpeg in PIL.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
PIL has worked fine for me in the past, when it comes to viewing/uploading images.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It likely only needs the zip decoder to save the jpeg. I think I needed to follow these steps in OS X to preview jpegs.

It probably means you need to:

- Download [the PIL source](http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz).
- Download the zlib library.
- [Point the PIL source to the zlib library.](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm)
- Build PIL.

Comment: You could download the zlib and then just reinstall pil with pip. You shouldn't need to build it from source.

Comment: [Mac OS X PIL JEPG and PNG issues](https://github.com/jpcummins/jipsta.com/blob/master/posts/fixing-pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available-error.md),

This Post help me out of both PNG and JPEG issue with PIL. (**decoder zip not available** and **decoder jpeg not available** )

Answer (score 116):

```
sudo pip uninstall PIL
sudo pip install pillow
```

^^ fixed it for me.

[Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) is a fork of PIL that is compatible with pip/setuptools and gets a little better maintenance. <strike>I haven't seen any API differences yet.</strike>

Edit: There is one notable API difference. PIL exposes Image as a top-level namespace, so you can

```
import Image # in PIL only
```

but

```
from PIL import Image  # in pillow or PIL
```

- Thanks, Leopd!

Comment: Fixed my problem! This is a lot simpler than compiling PIL manually. Thank you!

Comment: Small API difference - `import Image` works in PIL, not pillow.  pillow requires `from PIL import Image`

Comment: This also solves the problem described here: http://osdir.com/ml/python-numeric-general/2009-07/msg00124.html where numpy array doesn't actually create an array, but something like <PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile instance at 0xd1a050> depending on the image type. I think the API change makes a lot of sense as well...

Comment: Before running the pillow install, I would recommend installing the zlib and jpeg dev headers with "sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev"  This will ensure that .png and .jpg export work properly and are compiled in.

Comment: Didn't help on OS X Mavericks :(

Comment: If you are reinstalling Pillow after installing zlib, you need to recompile Pillow: `pip --no-cache-dir install Pillow`

Answer (score 41):

The more detail installation PIL with zlib library in Ubuntu 64 bit :

http://obroll.com/install-python-pil-python-image-library-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

For the lazy (credits to @**meawoppl** for the `apt-get`):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: For the lazy:

sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev

Comment: If you happen to be developing for pebble and come here because the zip decoder not available. Install these libraries and reinstall pillow. Installing pillow again, will rebuild the library with these dependencies included.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, look at the answer by JohnPang which worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this problem on a **64bit ubuntu 13.04 desktop version** and here is how I resolved it.

try to  reinstall PIL, and pay attention to the output info after you reinstalled:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26)
              [GCC 4.7.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
--- JPEG support available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

notice that there is a line :`*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available`,
which means PIL have been built without ZLIB support, and I fixed it by doing this:

first you should have these packages install: **libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev

# create these links, if already exists, remove it and re-link it
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib

# reinstall PIL
pip uninstall PIL
pip install PIL
```

This time, there should be a line `--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available` in the output.

Reference: http://jj.isgeek.net/2011/09/install-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-ubuntu-oneiric-64bits/

Comment: If you see a `_imagingft.c:73:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory` error after this just link one more library: `ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype2/freetype`  (I believe this happens if you have `apt-get install python-imaging`)

Answer (score 9):

I encountered same problem.  It seems to me that Pillow and pillow (different case in 'p') are two different packages.  So, if you are using Pillow, `pip install pillow` might not help.  Here is my solution:

```
$ pip uninstall Pillow
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
$ pip install -I Pillow
```

First two lines are to remove any pillow or Pillow package.

Third line is to install the two required packages.

Forth is re-install Pillow.

Note, if you are using virtualenv, `pip install/uninstall` must be run under virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed this on OS X Mavericks was by doing this:

Install brew:

http://brew.sh/

Install pip:

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

With those in place, you can do this:

```
sudo brew install lzlib     # installs zlib
pip uninstall PIL
pip install --no-index -f http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/ -U PIL
```

After that, it was working fine. For an explanation of the third line, check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486396/290072

Answer (score 1):

on mac

```
sudo brew install lzlib     # installs zlib
pip uninstall PIL
pip install PIL
```

Comment: Please elaborate some more.  It is really hard to tell what you are saying.

Comment: and `sudo brew install lzlib` just says "brew: command not found" on mine.

Answer (score 1):

I use 64bit ubuntu 14.04LTS desktop version, and I tried Johnny Zhao's answer.
When

```
exec sudo easy_install PIL
```

I got an error:

```
can't find freetype/fterrors.h
```

and I find freetype2 in /usr/include/

You could solve it by:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype
```

then install will be success

Comment: This happens because you have python-imaging installed with `apt-get install python-imaging`.  If you just install `libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev` on their own without all of python-imaging, you wont get this error.

Answer (score 1):

The cause may be you've installed Pillow without zlib support.

On CentOS 7:

```
yum install zlib zlib-devel
pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

And if you are using for a webapp restart your webserver to apply.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but if you're using a virtualenv, the "pip install Pillow --upgrade" should be done inside the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

on my case, i just remore python-image, make sure that libz is ready  then reinstall PIL, more detail you can see on my post here :

http://febru.soluvas.com/2014/03/solved-openerp-7-ioerror-decoder-zip.html

Answer (score 0):

[Mac OS X PIL JEPG and PNG issues](https://github.com/jpcummins/jipsta.com/blob/master/posts/fixing-pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available-error.md) (same for linux os), this Post help me out of both PNG and JPEG issues with PIL : 
**decoder zip not available** and **decoder jpeg not available**

Make sure JPEG and ZLIB are available, when you install / reinstall PIL :

```
$ cd Imaging-1.1.7
$ python setup.py build_ext -i
$ python selftest.py

--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the  version 2.8.0 it works fine  me

```
pip install -Iv Pillow==2.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

On `Ubuntu 18` I have had to install `pillow 2.8.1`:

```
pip install Pillow==2.8.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

    `$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
    $ sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib`

Starting from version 3.0.0 Pillow needs libjpeg. If the issue persists, there might be some package incompatibility. Save some time and try the previous version:

    `$ pip install Pillow==2.8.1`

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Monterey (12.2) installing rather old Pillow version 2.8.2 required following procedure:

- I needed to install zlib first:

  ```
  brew install zlib
  ```
- to get information where inludes/libs are stored:

  ```
  brew info zlib
  ```

  I found information as:

  ```
  For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
  ```
- I wanted to be sure so I checked if `zlib.h`exists:

  ```
  ls -al /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include/zlib.h
  ```
- based on information from previous steps setup C/C++ build_ext environment variables, in my case this was:

  ```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
  export CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
  ```

  NOTE: I needed to add `CFLAGS` too, probably due C compiler is used (Pillow <=5.*), not C++.
- finally build it (note that `--no-cache-dir` will force download and build):

  ```
  pip install --no-cache-dir --force "Pillow==2.8.2"
  ```
- Note that zlib is required starting with Pillow 3+, so 2.8.2 will not
  complain if zlib is not found (versions 3+ will stop build).
  Therefore after build/install is done one should test if `zip_decoder` is
  available like this:

  ```
  python -c "from PIL import _imaging as x; print(x.zip_decoder); print('OK')"
  ```

### Additionally

Single shell command which will redownload and rebuild everyting:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include" \
CFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include" \
pip install --no-cache-dir --force "Pillow==2.8.2"
```

Another alternative would be to symlink zlib include/lib files/folders to appropriate standard include/lib files/folders.

Answer (score -1):

You should match Pillow's version your python version.