# Sorl Thumbnail with Django in Mac OSX 10.7.2

Tags: django, macos, osx-lion, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I installed PIL, jpeg-8c, freetype-2.4.5 and sorl thumbnail. In my project, I have put ***sorl.thumbnail*** in **settings.py** . But when I use this code lines:

```
>>> from apps.news.models import Newtest
>>> im = get_thumbnail( Newtest.objects.all()[0].image.name, '60')
```

*Newtest.objects.all()[0].image* is one picture in my project.

and the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/shortcuts.py", line 8, in get_thumbnail
    return default.backend.get_thumbnail(file_, geometry_string, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/base.py", line 61, in get_thumbnail
    thumbnail)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/base.py", line 86, in _create_thumbnail
    image = default.engine.create(source_image, geometry, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/engines/base.py", line 16, in create
    image = self.colorspace(image, geometry, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/engines/base.py", line 34, in colorspace
    return self._colorspace(image, colorspace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl_thumbnail-11.09-py2.7.egg/sorl/thumbnail/engines/pil_engine.py", line 56, in _colorspace
    return image.convert('RGB')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 679, in convert
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder zip not available
```

Someone know why is it??

thx

Comment: seems like this thread > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/need-help-with-a-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have resolved this problem, I removed PIL and install this package libjpeg-libpng, installed PIL another time and updgrade PIL.

```
$ pip uninstall pil
```

Install package

```
$ pip install pil --upgrade
```