# PIL says it has "support available" but still gives IOError when saving files

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, pip

I am using PIL through virtualenv on ubuntu, installed with pip. I have changed the setup.py file to point to the decoders libaries. 
I get this message when I install PIL:

`PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY`

```
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Aug 11 2011, 12:16:10)
              [GCC 4.6.1]

--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
```

But I still get "IOError: decoder jpeg not available" and "IOError: 'decoder zip not available'" messages when i'm saving a file.
What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think I already experienced the same problem. Also, I think this is a duplicate of this
[About the PIL Error -- IOError: decoder zip not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/need-help-with-a-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available)

1. Download PIL Source
2. Download zlib
3. Point PIL source to zlib
4. Rebuild PIL

Comment: I had done that already, didn't work. I'm not getting a "decoder zip not available" message on install,they are similar problems, but it's not a duplicate.