# decoder zip not available (Windows 7)

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I installed django-photologue. But then when I try to save a photo in django admin it throws this error:

> 'decoder zip not available'

I have already un-installed and re-installed PIL. I hope someone can help me with the complete steps on how to overcome this error.

Comment: Have a look at this post ["Need help with a PIL Error — IOError: decoder zip not available"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/need-help-with-a-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available), it may be of some help.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows install PIL using the binary installer from [the PIL website](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) instead of using pip.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this cleanly on Windows with `pip install --use-wheel Pillow`. I'm not sure what changed because the PILLOW installs used to work on my windows setup. I must have some mixed versions or the default behaviors have changed.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following instructions:

```
sudo pip uninstall PIL
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjpeg62-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib
sudo pip install -U PIL
```

That should solve PIL problem `decoder zip not available`.

Comment: Any idea what was on the link you referenced since its broken?

Comment: Do you have a solution for Windows 7 as in the question title? The above seems to be for a Debian derived system.