# Python Imaging Library IOError: decoder zip on draw.text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Right now this works:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 

im = Image.new("1", (176, 33))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle((10, 10, 20, 20), 1)

im.save("image.h", "XBM")
```

But if I try to draw text it fails with (IOError: decoder zip not available)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 

im = Image.new("1", (176, 33))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((30,0), "Hello World!", 1)

im.save("image.h", "XBM")
```

The exception gets raised on the draw.text line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359864/41576), as suggested:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install pillow
```