# Python Tkinter - Image not displaying

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm writing a short script to display a user selected image in a canvas. The image the user selects could be different sizes. In the long run I want to have the application maximise and present scroll bars if the image loaded is larger than the screen resolution, however I have what is most likely a simple problem, the image selected isn't loaded into the Canvas. I just need another set of eyes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Menu, BOTH, NW
import Image 
import ImageTk
import tkFileDialog

appname = "example"

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title( appname )

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open File", command=self.fileOpen)

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    def fileOpen(self):
    file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(
        parent=self.parent,
        mode='rb',
        title='Choose a file',
        filetypes=[ ( "Image files",("*.jpg", "*.jpeg" ) )] )

    if file != None:

        self.img = Image.open(file)
        self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.img.size[0]+20, 
           height=self.img.size[1]+20)
        canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def filePref(self):
    self.quit()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Why doesn't the image load into the canvas when selected? I don't get an error displayed.
How can I maxmimise the whole window if the image is larger than the initial window size?
How can I add scroll bars if the image is larger than screen resolution?

Thanks

Comment: The code indentation looks messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the reason you are not seeing the image is format limitations of TK Image class. I suggest using [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) or [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) which has a TK compatible image class, and has better [image format support](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html) (You can try opening a GIF file to make sure it is the reason).

To run this code you need python imaging library, and its [ImageTk](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html) module installed on your machine. In Ubuntu you may install like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
```

Here is the desired application code (I changed the class structure a bit, but it's just personal preference). Vertical and horizontal scrollbars are enabled for the Canvas as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog

appname = "example"

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        if not root:
            root = Tk()
        self.root = root
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.root.title(appname)
        menubar = Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open File", command=self.fileOpen)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.scrollbar_vert = Scrollbar(self.root)
        self.scrollbar_vert.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.scrollbar_hor = Scrollbar(self.root)
        self.scrollbar_hor.config(orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.scrollbar_hor.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def onExit(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def fileOpen(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(
                parent=self.root,
                mode='rb',
                title='Choose a file',
                filetypes=[ ( "Image files",("*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif") ), ("All files", ("*.*"))] )

        if filename == None:
            return
        self.img = Image.open(filename)
        self.photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.canvas.pack_forget()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=self.img.size[0], height=self.img.size[1])
        self.canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.photo_image)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_vert.set)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_hor.set)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(ALL))
        self.scrollbar_vert.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar_hor.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = App(root)
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you are still having troubles opening PNG or JPG images, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/about-the-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available) might help.