# Import Image on windows

Tags: python, image, decoder

I have problem with import Image library in Python 2.7 on Windows. When I write:

```
import Image
```

I have error:

`No module named Image`

Library is added in project settings so I tried

`from PIL import Image`

Unfortunately now I have next error

```
raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder zip not available
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Assuming the rest of your Python installation is working, I would try manually downloading and installing the [`pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) module from the pypi package index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544155/about-the-pil-error-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: your target OS is ?

Answer (score 2):

For windows:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

then in your python code:

```
from PIL import Image
```