# OSError: decoder zip not available

Tags: python, pip, installation, python-imaging-library, tesseract

```
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("C:/Users/Abir Khan/Desktop/IIT B/Untitled.png")
text = pt.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Comment: Do post the traceback (error) you're getting

Comment: OS version? `Python` version? `pip` version? `PIL` or `Pillow`, and what version? How did you install `PIL`?

Answer (score 1):

OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
pip version: 20.2.4
requirements.txt: Pillow==2.8.1

Upgrading Pillow via `pip install --upgrade Pillow` to version `8.0.1` worked for me perfectly.

I have tried several different approaches like installing `zlib` and `lzlib` through `brew` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It likely only needs the zip decoder to save the jpeg. I think I needed to follow these steps in OS X to preview jpegs.

this might help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544159/8074624