# Python - package installed with easy_install is not being detected (PIL 1.1.7)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, setuptools, easy-install

I installed PIL with easy_install but for some reason when I run a file that uses it, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Does anyone know why this could be?

I think it's also worth mentioning that I installed web.py through easy_install and it's working fine.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. To me, it looks like a bug in PIL easy_install process. The library is installed, but you have to leave out PIL from imports (aka `import Image` works), which is obviously wrong.

To solve, don't use easy_install to perform the install. Download the tar package and `python setup.py install` it. This will work.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps that file is using a different python via its shebang line?
Try interactive interpreter and do a `import pil` and see if it works, if yes, then fixing the shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/python`) on top of file in the question might help.

Comment: import pil on the interactive interpreter gives me the same error.

Comment: Then PIL is not installed for your active interpreter. Try to figure out for which Python PIL is installed by looking at /usr/lib/pythonxx directories. It would be under site-packages and try to use that python. Or Download PIL Source and install it for your python interpreter which is active.

Answer (score 3):

Does the file you are running use the same version of Python that you installed PIL to?

If, for e.g. the file uses python 2.7, but your system also has 2.6, and PIL was installed there, that may be the issue.

Using easy_install with a version number might help:

```
easy_install-X.X pil
```

so for python 2.7, it would be:

```
easy_install-2.7 pil
```

---

PIL also has some issues with naming when used with easy_install, 
see:

1. http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/778318
2. [The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout)

But even with that you should still be able to import pil so I don't think that is the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using MAC OS, I have written a little tutorial on how to install libjpeg, PIL and image successfully on MAC OS X

Hope this helps.
[Libjpeg, PIL, Snow leopard](http://appelfreelance.com/2010/06/libjpeg-pil-snow-leopard-python2-6-_jpeg_resync_to_restart/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem configuring PIL after installing mac os Lion.
This post [The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout) shows the directives to install using a link with a fixed version.

Regards,
AT