# What is going on with PIL and the import statement

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I find this code in Django:

```
# Try to import PIL in either of the two ways it can end up installed.
try:
    from PIL import ImageFile as PILImageFile
except ImportError:
    import ImageFile as PILImageFile
```

and up until recently, I just blew it off as unimportant.   However I built PIL under my virtualenv in windows and all of a sudden

```
from PIL import Image
```

doesn't work anymore, I have to use

```
import Image
```

So, now I want to understand why and what is going on.

Initially I was using PIL installed with the [windows installer](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  But I [needed read support for Group4 Faxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034015/handling-group4-tiff-images-in-python) so I did the mods and then got PIL to build and install under virtualenv on windows (something that is trivial on linux and a PITA on windows).  But, now I have to use the second form of import, even though `pip freeze` shows that `PIL==1.1.7` in installed.

How is it that first import form doesn't work even though PIL appears to be installed, and the second form works (and the PIL code is functioning), indicating it is installed, but doesn't show up under PIL.

Comment: Please always describe *how* something isn't working, not just *that* it isn't.  Also include any traceback generated.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear, the imports you need to use the Image class change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: From the comment to my answer by @cgohlke, [this will change in PIL1.2](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2011-January/006650.html):

> the support for importing from the standard
>   namespace [has been dropped]; PIL now lives in the PIL namespace only

---

I think the Django comment is pretty clear:

```
# Try to import PIL in either of the two ways it can end up installed.
```

PIL can either be installed as a single package, and you access the modules within it:

```
from PIL import ImageFile as PILImageFile
```

or the modules can each be installed separately:

```
import ImageFile as PILImageFile
```

So PIL is installed, it is just split up into it's component modules.

It's also the issue in [The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout), and @Ignacio mentions in a comment that the [PIL tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm) actually expects it to be installed this way, the very first chunk of code starts:

```
>>> import Image
```

not `from PIL import Image`.

I agree this is confusing behavior, but I guess it's a relatively large package so they might think it's easier to not have to deal with an extra level of depth.

This seems to be the problem in [Python - package installed with easy_install is not being detected (PIL 1.1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085229/python-package-installed-with-easy-install-is-not-being-detected-pil-1-1-7) although only the last answerer there figured it out, the rest of the people don't know what is going on.

Comment: In my case, I'm installing it as `python setup.py install` and I have to do `import Image`.  When I use the windows Installer, I use `from PIL import Image`.  [I figured out a way to manually fix it](http://codemonkey.intomec.com/blog/group-4-faxes-with-pil/) and added it to my blog.

Comment: Hence the question, what is actually going on with PIL.  Obviously something is messed up or packages like Django wouldn't have workarounds to deal with the "2 ways" it can be installed.

Comment: But the point is that you shouldn't "Fix" it, it's considered correct behavior. It's also funny that you linked to your own blog and yet it's a (perhaps temporarily) dead link.

Comment: python setup.py install leaves it unencapsulated, using the windows installer leaves it encapsulated.  Both of those are from the same author, consistent it isn't.  Because of that lack of consistency we see hacks in the Django code.  SOMETHING is wrong.

Comment: Note that `import Image` will not work any longer in PIL 1.2+ <http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2011-January/006650.html>

Comment: Edited into my post, nice job finding that.

Comment: I wish this failed at import time. Instead, when I upgraded PIL, `Image.open` just started failing for me with `IOError: cannot identify image file 'test.jpg'`.