# Python Imaging Library (PIL) in virtualenv on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, distutils

I've got a python program that is using a ridiculous amount of extensions, so I'm trying to set up a virtualenv for it. However, one of the libraries it uses is PIL. After installing it, I get an import error on PIL.

This problem has been identified at the link below, but the solution there does not work for me (possibly because I'm using windows? I don't know.)

[The problem with installing PIL using virtualenv or buildout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout)

I used easy_install on the repackaged package in a fresh virtualenv, with no luck. Does anybody have ideas what might be causing this, or where to look to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `easy_install pip` then `pip install PIL` , to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was whether I was importing PIL.Image or simply Image. The virtualenv used Image, whereas my Python installation used PIL.image.