# How may i install the Python Imaging Library to django environment?

Tags: django, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I am currently finding it hard to install `PIL` on precise pangolin.
 I have followed this tutorial (http://www.sandersnewmedia.com/why/2012/04/16/installing-pil-virtualenv-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin/)

When I do:

```
pip install PIL
```

I get the error:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
No distributions at all found for PIL
```

Looked around google but to no avail.

Comment: Have a look  at the top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485295/the-problem-with-installing-pil-using-virtualenv-or-buildout). You might find it easier to install ['pillow'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) which is a more pip-friendly fork of PIL

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pillow
--> pip install Pillow